# Python data source - first two columns disappear

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have started using PowerBI and am using Python as a data source with the code below. The source data can be downloaded [from here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7ec2290c6fb1bf1fb2f01c1011b1ad6f20220808213036/98e271) (it's about 700 megabytes). The data is originally [from here](https://zenodo.org/record/5589597) (contained in *IOT_2019_pxp.zip*).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

path = /path/to/file

to_chunk = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,'A.txt'), delimiter = '\t', header = [0,1], index_col = [0,1], 
                       iterator=True, chunksize=1000)

def chunker(to_chunk):
    to_concat = []
    for chunk in to_chunk:
        try:
            to_concat.append(chunk['BG'].loc['BG'])
        except:
            pass
    return to_concat
    
A = pd.concat(chunker(to_chunk))

I = np.identity(A.shape[0])

L = pd.DataFrame(np.linalg.inv(I-A), index=A.index, columns=A.columns)
```

The code simply:

1. Loads the file A.txt, which is a symmetrical matrix. This matrix has every *sector* in every *region* for both rows and columns. In `pandas`, these form a `MultiIndex`.
   [image]
2. Filters just the region that I need which is `BG`. Since it's a symmetrical matrix, both row and column are filtered.
3. The inverse of the matrix is calculated giving us `L`, which I want to load into PowerBI. This matrix now just has a single regular `Index` for *sector*. [image]

This is all well and good however when I load into PowerBI, the first column (sector names for each row i.e. the DataFrame `Index`) disappears. When the query gets processed, it is as if it were never there. This is true for both dataframes `A` and `L`, so it's not an issue of data processing. The column of row names (the DataFrame index) is still there in Python, PowerBI just drops it for some reason.

[image: what I see in PBI after I load the data with the code above]

I need this column so that I can link these tables to other tables in my data model. Any ideas on how to keep it from disappearing at load time?

Comment: Not a Pandas expert, but it appears that PowerBI doesn't load the Index.  If you make it a column, it should load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, calling `reset_index()` removed the index from the dataframes and they got loaded like regular columns. For whatever reason, PBI does not properly load `pandas` indices.

For a regular 1D index, I had to do `S.reset_index()`.

For a `MultiIndex`, I had to do `L.reset_index(inplace=True)`.